# React: Why is a variable in local storage resetting to undefined after briefly being the desired value?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am new to React and was writing some toy code whose desired behavior is to allow a user to enter their name in the form and the page will display "Hello {user's name}" after submitting.

However, the observed behavior is that the page flickers briefly to render "Hello {user's name}" and then returns to the default rendering as if no name had been submitted.

My current approach is to save the user's name in local storage upon submission with a `useEffect`. However, from observing console logs, the local storage appears to be resetting the `name` variable to `undefined` immediately after setting it to the inputted name.
Below is the code:

```js
function NameForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem("name") || "");
  useEffect(() => {
    setName(window.localStorage.setItem("name", name));
    console.log(name);
  }, [name]);
  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          setName(event.target.elements.usernameInput.value);
          return false;
        }}
      >
        <label>Enter your name</label>
        <input id="usernameInput" />
        <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      </form>
      <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NameForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-hill-gfkrp?file=/src/App.js:76-773) is also the codesandbox used to run the code.

Why is this unexpected behavior occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**why unexpected behavior**
`window.localStorage.setItem("name", name)` returns undefined. So you are essencially doing `setName(undefined)` in your useEffect. Hence the issue.

**how to fix?**
You can fix in a number of ways. One way is to simply get rid of your useEffect and do localStorage.setItem in `onSubmit` and then do setName immediately.

[Updated codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/localstorage-react-fix-bqi2x?file=/src/App.js)

```js
<>
      <form
        onSubmit={event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          window.localStorage.setItem(
            "name",
            event.target.elements.usernameInput.value
          );
          setName(event.target.elements.usernameInput.value);
        }}
      >
        <label>Enter your name</label>
        <input id="usernameInput" />
        <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      </form>
      <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
    </>
```

You can solve your issue with [controlled input](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-controlled-components).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to apply a condition before setting the value. Once the form is submitted, your `name` value is becoming `undefined` and that is getting stored.

Now, you'd say that you have used `useState(window.localStorage.getItem("name") || "")`, so how can it be undefined?
This is because of the race condition. It takes some time to `setItem` in the local storage and before it is set, your component is getting rendered.

Also, you can use `localStorage` directly instead of using `window.localStorage`.
Here is what you need to do:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (name) setName(window.localStorage.setItem("name", name));
  console.log(name);
}, [name]);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish needs to be done in another way. You need to set local storage when user submits the `name`. After that, you can also call `setName` to update component. What you want to do in `componentDidMount` is to get the `name` from local storage. I [edited the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-glitter-jru6p?file=/src/App.js:0-861) you provided.

I am also leaving a copy of the code below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function NameForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem("name") || "");
  useEffect(() => {
    setName(window.localStorage.getItem("name"));
    console.log(name);
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          let new_name = event.target.elements.usernameInput.value;
          window.localStorage.setItem("name", new_name);
          setName(new_name);
          return false;
        }}
      >
        <label>Enter your name</label>
        <input id="usernameInput" />
        <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      </form>
      <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NameForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```